# PowerShell script to install PS5.0 update then rerun current script, elevated, using the new version of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, updates

I have a script that requires PS 5.0, and machines that may well only have PS2.0 or PS3.0 installed when my script runs. I can automate the update of PowerShell, but the currently running script will not be using the revised powershell version.

I could just require folks to update before running my script, but for my target audience that is a difficult proposition. I would much rather have my script (which is launched elevated) install the update, and then trigger itself to run again, but with the revised PowerShell version.

To that end, I could...

1. Automate a reboot with a one time logon with admin credentials and runonce the current script. UGLY, because automating logon with admin credentials is bad juju.
2. Trigger a reboot that ensures the new version of PS is in use, and trigger the script to run again with the same arguments without a logon. But is it possible to trigger a script to run elevated pre-logon? And can I keep a user from logging in until my script is done? If I reboot and run before the logon, a user might actually logon for real while the update is still running. I have looked at ways to provide a message at the logon screen to minimize the chance of this, but they are kludgy at best and users can always ignore the message.
3. Create two Scheduled Tasks, one to refresh PS version in use, second to rerun script. Dependent on the ability to actually refresh the PS version in use. And has to be doable using PS2.0 to create the scheduled tasks. Can this even be done? This is actually my preferred option, because then I can provide a message that the machine is still updating.
4. ??? Better ideas I haven't come up with yet?
5. Can't be done, suck it up.

Note that I can't assume logon scripts, GPO, SCCM or anything similar here. I am targeting firms that do not have that kind of expertise, and those options are simply non starters.

Hopefully someone has some thoughts beyond "The answer is 5".

Comment: *"I would much rather have my script (which is launched elevated) install the update"* Uhh... you really don't want your script to update key system components on its own, there is no telling what other things this can break.

Comment: @tomalak I'm not sure I follow? Microsoft even provides info on how to use powershell to update WMF. Or are you saying updating WMF could break other scripts in the environment? For what it is worth, the entire point of my script is to do updates. It will only be run because IT has decided to do updates and initiated the script. So no one will be blindsided, they will be choosing to update, and my approach just saves them a step, because it updates the environment AND updates what they wanted updated.

Comment: Yes, I think it could break other scripts in the environment in weird and unexpected ways. I've had scripts break because of unanticipated changes to WinRM between PS versions. It's definitely a risk. But of course it's also a matter of perspective. If your script's focus is to do system updates, doing a system update as part of the installation process might be defensible. If your script does other things (3rd party vendor application updates), doing a system update as part of the installation might not be defensible.

Comment: My personal preference would be to side-step the entire dilemma by ensuring that my script runs in the lowest-common-denominator environment, i.e. PS 2.0. Many things that are in PS 5.0 are merely syntactic sugar and can be done (or worked around) in PS 2.0 code, at the expense of some elegance in the code. PowerShell is not the most elegant language to begin with, so any losses in that department would be bearable.

Comment: @tomalak, interesting perspective. Thus far I have been targeting PS2.0 with just that thinking. But I am refactoring now, in part for OOP that is functional enough to do what I need in 5.0. And interestingly, I have asked questions about how to do something in PS2.0 and gotten the answer "Upgrade to 5.0, everyone should be at least using that now anyway". I may start another thread for a discussion of pros and cons both ways, since I suspect it's a rather complex topic. In the meantime, still hoping someone has a solution, since there is a real need for the option.

Comment: It's hard to pin down a definitive answer; this is very much opinion-based (i.e. off-topic on SO, strictly speaking). If you're determined on upgrading (and it sounds like your customers are unlikely to have sophisticated set-ups that lock you into a specific version of PS), you can certainly do that. Registering scheduled tasks that run elevated is certainly possible. According to [this post](https://adamtheautomator.com/upgrading-powershell-5-1/), upgrading PowerShell in an automated fashion for a variety of targets is not exactly what I would call trivial, though.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping it was a LITTLE easier than that. Given how much Microsoft pushes newest version, making it hard to actual do across an enterprise seems counter to their goals. But still, it's a thread to follow. Thanks for the link!